# How to stop this loop? And what is the best way to tell user the longest string they have entered?

Tags: python, loops

```
a = input('number of names: ')

count = 0

while a > 0:
    name = raw_input("Please enter filename:")
    count =+ 1
    if count == a:
       break
```

First and foremost, I'm pretty new to Python. I just started learning Python 10 days ago.

My first question is why doesn't this loop work?

And after performing a loop, I want to tell the user which one is the longest file name and the number of characters it has, but I don't know why.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: "… but I don't know why." - you probably don't know *how*.

Answer (score 5):

You probably intended to write `+=` instead of `=+`.

```
count += 1
```

The statement `count =+ 1` is equivalent to `count = (+1)`, i.e. it sets count to 1.

It would also be better to use a more explicit loop:

```
number_of_names = int(raw_input('Number of names:'))
names = []
for n in range(number_of_names):
    name = raw_input('Filename')
    names.append(name)
print max(names, key = len)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/t97O3)

Answer (score 2):

here is the answer but i think you should spend some time on basics, and 10 days are big enough for this work.

```
a = input('number of names: ')

count = 0
max = -1
while a > count:
    name = raw_input("Please enter filename:")
    count += 1
    l_max = len(name)
    if l_max > max:
        max = l_max
    if count == a:
        print max
        break
```

Comment: I used this method and it works perfectly
Thank you everyone for helping! :)

Daria

Comment: @DariaEgelhoff don't forget to accept this answer by clicking on a tick mark , so that others can also get benefit from this

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input('number of names: ')

count = 0
largest_str = ""
while count < a:
    name = raw_input("Please enter filename:")
    count += 1
    if len(largest_str) < len(name):
        largest_str = name

print largest_str
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your loop is not very good defined. You're now not using the counter to interrupt your loop, the condition

```
while count < a:
```

Would make your break-statement obsolete.

Then, be sure to check that a is really of type integer. You may be comparing integers with strings here.

Comment: No, he's not (at least as long as the user enters a number). `a` is an integer because he used `input()` instead of `raw_input()`. But it's still not good to do this. Better use `a = int(raw_input("Please enter..."))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input('number of names: ')

longest = ""

for i in xrange(a): #Use for loops where you can, they are more 'pythonic'
    name = raw_input("Please enter filename:")
    if len(longest) < len(name):
        longest = name

print("The longest filename is {} which is {} characters long.".format(longest, len(longest)))
```